# How can I connect several users to a same MySQL Database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm designing an android app on the android studio, and it's giving me an error when I'm trying to connect more than 2 or more users or 'Phones' at the same time to my MySQL database.

What I am thinking my error is, its that even though my DB has a usertable which I'm using it, I am connecting through the same user-admin created by the Cpanel to manage the DB.

I'm leaving my code here so you all can see it and if I have an error, try to fix it with your help. 
Connection php file

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'xxx');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'xxx');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

and my Login.php

```
<?php
require_once('Conexion.php');
$username = $_POST["Usuario"];
$passw = $_POST["Contrasena"];
$statement=mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT idTrabajador,`Nombre del Trabajador`,`Unidades por Vender`  FROM `tablausuario` WHERE `Usuario`=? AND Contrasena=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$passw);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$idTrabajador,$name,$uxv);
$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
$response["success"] = true;
$response["idTrabajador"] = $idTrabajador;
$response["Nombre del Trabajador"] = $name;
$response["Unidades por Vender"] = $uxv;
}
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

finally my AndroidActivity, where always shows me the AlertDialog message

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    editUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userLog);
    editPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passLog);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLog);
    btnOlvide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnolvLog);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgL);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int heg = display.getHeight();
    img.setMaxHeight(heg/3);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String userPass = editPass.getText().toString();
            final String userNam = editUsuario.getText().toString();
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            String idTra = jsonResponse.getString("idTrabajador");
                            String naMe = jsonResponse.getString("Nombre del Trabajador");
                            //String uxv = jsonResponse.getString("Unidades por Vender");
                            Intent openLog = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuPrincipal.class);
                            openLog.putExtra("idTrabajador", idTra);
                            openLog.putExtra("Nombre del Trabajador", naMe);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(openLog);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Error de Login, Verifique su conexion o los datos ingresados")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Reintentar", null).create().show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            RequestLogin loginRequest = new RequestLogin(userNam, userPass, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
```

Comment: and the error is??

Comment: @nogad, ok for example, i opened my app, i inserted the user and pass, and clicked 'btnLogin' on the phone1 all ok., but when i go to the phone2 trying to do the same process i inserted correctly all the field but automatically  sent me the "Login Error" message, and i am inserting the fields correctly and it doesn't open the second activity which its the successful login

Comment: @AlexAlfonso you check max connections of mysql?  https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404374/how-do-i-increase-the-mysql-connections-for-my-server

Comment: @DarckBlezzer, my server doesn't have or i dont see the my.cnf file, so i think i have to create one